# Is there a way to animate animatedContainer within a fixed width Container?

Tags: flutter

I'm having trouble simulating a "colour countdown" within my app. Basically, I want the inside container to slowly shrink (from top to bottom) while the outside container (with the border) stays the same in width and height. Right now, my code adjust both of the containers instead of just the innermost one.

Google's documentation and tutorials don't have much to say about this niche case. Is this even possible?

Below is what it looks like without setting a width and height to outside container
[Good trial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q90Fa.gif)

and here is what it looks like when I do set a width and height. 
[Bad trial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4caMs.gif)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'package:timely_flutter/scoped_models/model.dart';

class Timer extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Timer();
}

class _Timer extends State<Timer> {
  _Timer();

  MainModel model;
  var width = 600;
  var height = 500;
  var margin = EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0, left: 10.0);
  var backColor = Colors.black;
  var text = Text("Hello", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),);
  bool selected = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, model) {
        return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("clicked");
              setState(() {
                selected = !selected;
                print(selected);
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
//              height: height.toDouble(),
//              width: width.toDouble(),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
              ),
            child: new AnimatedContainer(
              height: selected ? height / 4: height / 1.5 ,
              width: width /1.5, // this will give you flexible width not fixed width
              margin: margin, // variable
              color: backColor,// variable
              duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: new Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: text, //varaible above
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: new Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: text, //variable above
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
        )
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The outer container will resize to fit the child widget unless set dimensions are given. Setting constant height and width to the parent container might help you or you can wrap the child container with a `SizedBox`

Answer (score 1):

Set a `width` and a `height` to the fixed `Container`, so that it won't resize to fit its `child`.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'package:timely_flutter/scoped_models/model.dart';

class Timer extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Timer();
}

class _Timer extends State<Timer> {
  _Timer();

  MainModel model;
  var width = 600;
  var height = 500;
  var margin = EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0, left: 10.0);
  var backColor = Colors.black;
  var text = Text("Hello", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),);
  bool selected = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, model) {
        return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("clicked");
              setState(() {
                selected = !selected;
                print(selected);
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              width: width,
              height: height,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
//              height: height.toDouble(),
//              width: width.toDouble(),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
              ),
            child: new AnimatedContainer(
              height: selected ? height / 4: height / 1.5 ,
              width: width /1.5, // this will give you flexible width not fixed width
              margin: margin, // variable
              color: backColor,// variable
              duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: new Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: text, //varaible above
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: new Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: text, //variable above
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
        )
      },
    );
  }
}
```